# Android Mediastore does not list MID & AAC files

Tags: android, audio, mp3, midi, aac

When using mediastore to list audio files from internal/external storage, AMR, OGG and MP3 are listed but MID and AAC are not. If I use Android file system API to list all the files, I can list the MID and AAC but can't play them, even though Android claims to support AAC.

Any ideas to this?

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

AAC decoding is only supported in 3.1+. I don't know what version ur working on, but that might be the issue.